# How to determine solutions to this differential equation in terms of this function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $s(x) := (\sin x) / x $ if $x \neq 0$, and let $s(0) = 1$; define $T(x) \colon = \int_0^x s(t) \ dt$. Then the function $f(x) \colon = x T(x) $ satisfies the differential equation $xy^\prime - y = x \sin x $ on the interval $(-\infty, +\infty)$. How to determine (in terms of $T(x)$) all solutions to this differential equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y$ satisfies $xy' - y  = x\sin x$. Then $z = y - f$ satisfies

$$x z' - z = x(y' - f') - (y-f) = (xy'-y) - (xf' - f) = x\sin x - x\sin x = 0$$

Note that we know all solution to the differential equation $xz'-z = 0$, it is $z = Cx$ for any constant $C$ (how?). Thus

$$y(x) =z(x) + f(x)=  Cx + f(x)\ .$$

This technique is common in solving linear differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Write the DEQ as:

$$y' - \dfrac{y}{x} = \sin x$$

Now, use the integrating factor:

$$\mu(x) = e^{\int (1/x)~dx} = \dfrac{1}{x}$$

This will yield:

$$y(x) = c x + \sin x = x( c + Si(x))$$

Where $Si(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$. This is called $s(x)$ in your problem. Also, we have:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} Si(x) = 1$$

Hopefully, you can handle the rest.